# System.Net.CertificatePolicy to ServerCertificateValidationCallback Accept all certificate policies

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I've downloaded some sample code that is a bit outdated. It has the following class:

```
public class TrustAllCertificatePolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy
{
    public TrustAllCertificatePolicy()
    { }

    public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp,
              System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert,
              WebRequest req, 
              int problem)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

later on in the code it calls the following:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
```

It gives the following warning:

> Warning   1   'System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy' is obsolete: 'CertificatePolicy is obsoleted for this type, please use ServerCertificateValidationCallback instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'

What is the current procedure to achieve the equivalent functionality?

I've read an [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c98ea134-c582-4c2a-8c42-d7e31f7fe389/certificatepolicy-vs-servercertificatevalidationcallback) on MSDN but I'm unsure of how to convert? This is for a class library. I appologize if it seems as though I havn't researched this enough but when it comes to ssl certificates, it's a bit out of my realm. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like we use the same example code, thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Include the following class in your code

```
 public static class SSLValidator
        {
            private static bool OnValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
                                                      SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            {
                return true;
            }
            public static void OverrideValidation()
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                    OnValidateCertificate;
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            }
        }
```

Then call the following before you make service call but be careful to remove this code on the production when you have real certs

```
SSLValidator.OverrideValidation();
```

Or you can do the following to use it only for debugging

```
#if DEBUG

            SSLValidator.OverrideValidation();
#endif
```

Comment: This solution did not have any negative effects on the application. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the last line of code in the class 'SSLValidator'. the 'ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue' part. What is 'Expect100Continue'?

Comment: You have detailed explanation right here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue.aspx

Comment: This is a clear, concise answer that helped me out of a similar jam.  Thanks Dan.

Comment: @DanHunex thanks this was very helpful for use in PowerShell as well. I modified it a bit so that the result can be undone, and I've [written a short blog post about it](http://www.briantist.com/errors/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssltls-secure-channel/). I've linked to this answer, but if you have a web site or something else I can link to let me know.

Comment: @briantist that is great Brian. I dont have a website. I m happy you wrote article on it

Comment: What should be done in a non-DEBUG / production scenario?

Answer (score 4):

I use the following when connecting to other web services.

```
//workaround for SSL certificate issue
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
  (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

per comments I need to add to the blurb - DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION
(if you do - please send $500 to my paypal account)

Comment: This is a major security risk. Check the answer above you.

Comment: @OriNachum you are absolutely correct.   This should not be used in production.  Its just for getting started in a development environment.

Comment: Please edit it so it clarifies this is for development environment only as to avoid confusing starting developers