# Amazon s3 file upload working on live environment but error on test environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

> [AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation

**Code:**

```
public bool UploadFileOnS3Server_sk(string folderName, string fileName)
{
    string _awsAccessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["awsAccessKey"].ToString();
    string _awsSecretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["awsSecretKey"].ToString();
    string _bucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bucketName"].ToString();
    FileInfo filename = new FileInfo(fileName);
    // string contents = File.ReadAllText(filename.FullName);
    String delimiter = "/" + folderName;
    using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Uploading an object");
        WritingAnObject(string.Concat(_bucketName, delimiter), filename.FullName, filename.Name);
    }
    return true;
}
static void WritingAnObject(string bucketName, string filePath, string keyName)
{
    try
    {
        AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
        {
            UseHttp = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseHttps"])
        };
        PutObjectRequest putRequest1 = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = keyName,
            ContentBody = "sample text",
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
        };

        PutObjectResponse response1 = client.PutObject(putRequest1);

        // 2. Put object-set ContentType and add metadata.
        PutObjectRequest putRequest2 = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = keyName,
            FilePath = filePath,
            ContentType = "text/plain",
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
        };
        putRequest2.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle");

        PutObjectResponse response2 = client.PutObject(putRequest2);

    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
    {
        if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
            (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
            ||
            amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
            Console.WriteLine(
                "For service sign up go to http://aws.amazon.com/s3");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Error occurred. Message:'{0}' when writing an object"
                , amazonS3Exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you use HTTPS or HTTP on your live environment? As I would think that is the likely cause.

Comment: used https on live environment  and it working on test environment i have used http its not working and on localhost it is working

Comment: done with test environment as https  still error  response as The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454292/system-net-certificatepolicy-to-servercertificatevalidationcallback-accept-all-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa