# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. Works with SOAP UI but not .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting an SSL error when making a SOAP call with an SSL certificate: **"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."**

The weird thing is that if I load the certificate in Firefox and visit the endpoint or make a call to the API without sending any data, I don't get any error message and it connects successfully. The company exposing the API has also mentioned that the certificate is kosher.

The certificate I'm loading has full privileges to "Everyone". I've tried every solution I've seen on the internet but still getting the error.

Here is my code that creates the request:

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(plugin.EndPoint);
 request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
 request.Method = "POST";
```

The code to get the certificate (I've also tried with a pfx):

```
var cert = new 
 509Certificate2(@"C:\clientcert.p12", "FakePassword");
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

and the code for the request:

```
  byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    dataStream.Close();


                    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            StreamReader reader = 
new StreamReader(responseStream ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
                            return reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Edit:

Here is the trace output from running the request:

System.Net Information: 0 : [11844] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=CertUnknown).
System.Net Error: 0 : [11844] Exception in HttpWebRequest#63832831:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Error: 0 : [11844] Exception in HttpWebRequest#63832831::EndGetRequestStream - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..

I also changed the SecurityProtocol:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Second Edit: I can get it to work in SoapUI but not in the .NET application by just loading the SSL certificate from the file system in SOAP UI.

Comment: is that all the exception ?

Comment: sadly yes :( the certunknown is from tracing and the SSL/TLS error is the WebException thrown

Comment: It has to do with your certificate. it says CertUnknown. Are you sure the cert works

Comment: It does when I load it with SoapUI but not the .NET application. The API author also validated the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is the cert is self signed so there isn't a chain. I'm loading it from my filesystem and not windows certificate store but I added all permissions to "everyone" in the the mmc console and the actual file. I also tried adding it to "trusted root authority" and "personal" and load them using a thumbpring but I'm getting the same error every time.

Comment: If it is selfsigned , try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454292/system-net-certificatepolicy-to-servercertificatevalidationcallback-accept-all-c/18454416#18454416

Comment: I have this:   System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

Comment: SOAP UI is written in Java, so it uses a different crypto stack. .NET Framework apps use Windows crypto stack, which can be different. Which account do you install the self-signed certificate to? The computer account and your personal account are separate. Besides, what kind of .NET app? ASP.NET and console apps also differ.

Comment: I installedt to a bunch of stores on local computer but in my code now I'm just loading it from the filesystem. It is an app.net mvc 4.5 web application.